# Reporting JMeter test failures

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

Bit of a general query really regarding how I could go about displaying failures textually, from a Jmeter run test, run via Jenkins?

I'm running a JMeter 'Smoke' test via a csv file (which simply lists a large amount of URLs), which will test whether the URL under test responds with a 200/301 page request.

At the moment, if an URL from the csv file under test fails (i.e. 404s), JMeter will (correctly) report this as a failure.

However, with there being 40,000+ URLs in the csv file, I really need this be more specific, ideally listing the actual URL(s) from the csv file that fail, rather than just a generic Failure message.

Is this possible, and if so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest and the easiest solution is just "telling" JMeter to save request URLs in .jtl results file. You can do this in at least 2 ways:

1. Once only: via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. Permanent. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   ```

In both cases you will have requests URLs stored in .jtl results file (which is basically CSV file by default) so you can sort out failures using `success` column and see failed URLs using [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) or equivalent.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Results File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)